# Alternative to elixir `mix.scriptsIn` in laravel-mix

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-elixir, laravel-mix

Laravel 5.4 introduces laravel-mix.
With elixir I had one task that loads all vendor files into one specific:

```
elixir(function (mix) {
  mix.stylesIn('public/vendor/css', 'public/css/vendor.css');

  mix.scriptsIn('public/vendor/js', 'public/js/vendor.js');
}
```

Is possible to do the same with laravel-mix?

Using `mix.js('/path/to/folder', 'public/js/vendor.js')` i get an error:

```
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it helps someone, laravel-mix has a `combine` function, that can be used for both css and js files:

```
//js files
mix.combine(['path/to/folder/js/*'], 'public/js/combined.js');

//and

//css files
mix.combine(['path/to/folder/css/*'], 'public/css/combined.css');
```

If the load order of each file is important in your case, it's better use `mix.scripts(...)` or some other option.

I just found it here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/mix-combine-all-js-in-folder.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [`.extract()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix#vendor-extraction) method.

**e.g**:

```
mix
    .js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js/app.js')
    .extract([
        'jquery',
    ]);
```

If you don't use CommonJS `require` or ES2015 `import` and you bundled all your libraries in one single file, you can use `.js()` method:

```
mix
    .js('resources/assets/js/vendor.js', 'public/js/vendor.js');
```

You can also concatenate your files using `.scripts()` :

```
mix.scripts([
    'public/js/admin.js',
    'public/js/dashboard.js'
], 'public/js/all.js');
```

Don't forget to inject `vendor.js` file in your html :

```
<script src="{{ mix('js/vendor.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: As I understand, the `extrac` will put the jquery library into a vendor.js file, but this not answer my question: I need to load all files inside a folder into one file, one alternative to elixir `scriptsIn` or `stylesIn` function.

Comment: I know the `scripts()` and `extract()` functions. As as asked, I need an alternative to elixir `scriptsIn` function, that is not mentioned in the docs. I just found a thread with the answer. Thanks for your attention anyway.